# PHP email script with server name

Tags: php, email, localhost

I have an email script that works fine on my server but when I put it on another apperently I need to change the server name from localhost to their name they have. The email script I have doesn't have a server name and I was wondering how I would do this? below is the script...

```
<?PHP
$email = $_POST["emailaddress"];
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$zipcode = $_POST["zipcode"];
$feedback = $_POST["feedback"];
$date=date("d-m-Y");

$to = "";
$subject = "New Feedback Received";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $email\n";

$message = "

<html>
<head></head>
<body>

A visitor to your website has left the following feedback; <br /><br />
Date: $date <br />
First Name: $firstname <br />
Last Name: $lastname <br />
Zip Code: $zipcode <br />
Email Address: $email <br />
Feedback: $feedback <br />

<img src=\"" />
</body>
</html>
";
$user = "$email";
$usersubject = "Thank You";

$userheaders = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$userheaders .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$userheaders .= "From: info@westmorelandberryfarm.com\n";
$usermessage =
"
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
Thank you for your feedback, your comments are important to us.
<br /><br />
We hope to see you at the Farm very soon!
<br /><br />
<br />
Tel:  <br />
<a href=\""</a><br />
<img src=\"" />
</body>
</html>
";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
mail($user,$usersubject,$usermessage,$userheaders);
$fh = fopen("feedback.txt", "a");
fwrite($fh, "Date:$date\r\nFirst Name:$firstname\r\nLast Name:$lastname\r\nEmail:$email\r\nZip   Code:$zipcode\r\nFeedback:$feedback\r\n \r\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: it is not apparent to me. What exactly is your question?

Comment: [Here](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm) is an example of sending mails with SMTP

Comment: How do I change the server name though? this is what I need to do.

Comment: what server are you talking about?

Comment: Just a regular server you would get from a hosting company.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting it on a live server env like `Amazon` or `Rackspace`, you will have a qualified server name, that you  can get from `$_SERVER[]` variable. But the major thing is you must ensure your server instance has got a `non-black listed ip,` or assign an elastic ip for delivery of mails on all domains.